# Rails and Multiple base URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So I'm beginning to think that this isn't possible because hours of googling are turning nothing up.

I have a single app that will live under multiple URLs being proxied from different servers.  I want to be able to access the same app using both:

example.com/mysite/
anotherexample.com/

Using a proxy (HAProxy, Apache, whatever) I can get either to work (or both) but the URLs on the page only work for one or the other.  Most notably the asset tags all start with /assets meaning that if I set the base url to be / then visit the site using the first url listed above I get asset tags that look like "example.com/assets" when what i want is "example.com/mysite/assets"

Are there any good workarounds for basing URLs on the request URL instead of a globally defined base?

Comment: can you just do something like mod_rewrite on the proxy to change example.com/assets to example.com/mysite/assets?

Comment: I think that might work, but you're destroying the entire namespace then.  The whole point of putting it in a subdirectory is to preserve any similarly named folders on the root.  i.e. I could no longer have example.com/assets for anything else.  In my case, I do need that directory for the main site that this sits under.

Comment: I'm wondering if using an asset_host might help solve the problem.  As long as you use only paths instead of URLs throughout the site everything should work properly, right?

Comment: Can you just assign both names to a single address (same `A` record in DNS)?  I may be misunderstanding your goal, but this seems like it's something you can solve more easily completely outside of Rails, either with the simple DNS solution, your web server configuration (Apache, nginx, whatever), or a proxy.

Comment: Jim, this won't work because I don't control both domains.  Well, I do, but they're in use in different ways.

Maybe this will make more sense with more context.  What I"m trying to do is create an api.  I have two domain names one for public access to my company, one for staff access.  On the staff side our portal for editing the data in the one API (hours of operation) the application goes on the root.  But on the public facing side we want the API to live in a namespace we have created for any and all APIs.  i.e. my.site.com/apis/

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html

something like this proc here:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
  if request.ssl?
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
  else
    "#{request.protocol}assets.example.com"
  end
}
```

You can inspect the request object or use some local environment variable or what ever logic to control the assest path.

I would look at something like phusion passenger as thier docs on advanced domain configuration are good:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Lastly, as long as you use the path helpers(root_path, image_tag, etc), the majority of rails doesn't care about the host/subdomain/whatever